# How to display graphs on linux terminal using python seaborn and matplotlib

Tags: python, seaborn

I wrote a script to display a histplot using seaborn and matplot. The python script is working fine when I run it on VS code. But when I run it using Linux terminal, the plot is not showing. I do not know what`s the problem here. My assignment requirement it to run the code through the terminal.

Here`s is the screenshot of the code on VS code:
[image: Output of the script on VS code]

Here`s the output of the code on terminal:

[image: output of code on linux terminal]

Comment: The terminal is traditionally a text-only device. Open a new graphical window to display graphics (or switch to a souped-up modern terminal; I hear Kitty supports inline graphics).

Comment: Thanks, I`ll search about it.